# How to selectively append to end of line using visual block mode?

Tags: visual-block

I am trying to use visual block mode to append a `,` to the end of `root_dir`, where `[]` is the cursor.

```lua
lspconfig.html.setup{
  root_dir = root_di[r]
}
lspconfig.cssls.setup{
  root_dir = root_dir
}
```

I tried to enter visual block mode, go down until I am on another `root_dir` and append comma.

```
<c-v> 3j A ,
```

But then it will become this:

```
lspconfig.html.setup{
  root_dir = root_dir,
}                    ,
lspconfig.cssls.setup,{
  root_dir = root_dir,
}
```

Is it possible to achieve what I want with visual block mode? I know I can use search and replace but I want to know if there is some other alternatives.

Comment: No, Visual Block mode will not work for that, you can't use `A` or `I` from Visual Block to affect only a few of the lines... You should use a macro or similar to make these edits if you have too many to do manually. For example, to add a comma to every line with a `root_dir` I'd use `:g/root_dir/norm A,` which will do the job. `:s` with a pattern matching `$` (end of the line) to add the comma there also an option.

Comment: `:g/root_dir/norm A` is really smart. Thanks